# Add ReportViewer to Toolbox VB.NET 2013

Tags: report, viewer, toolbox

I installed Report Viewer 2012 in VS 2013 (VB.NET), but it's not listed as an component in toolbox. Where is the location to reference the ReportViewer via browse, or how do I add the ReportViewer to toolbox?

I wasted all day trying to create a simple report.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this won't be useful to you anymore, but I hope it will be to someone else.

If you installed ReportViewer correctly on your computer, you must go to VisualStudio and **right click on the toolbar** (I recommend you do it on the General tab), and choose the option "**Choose elements**". Once there, check the **.NET tab** and look for **ReportViewer on the list**, and pick the one of the **Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms** namespace (there could be another one for WebForms, and that one you DON'T need in this case). That should do the trick.

**EDIT:** If you don't find the element, click on the Navigate button on the Choose elements dialog, and go to the next folder: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91 (the last folder may have a language acronym given by your language: en, es, fr, it, etc.). There, pick up the DLL that should load the component on your toolbar. For more info, [check this link](http://firebird-vbnet.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-get-ms-reportviewer-control-in.html).

I hope this helps. Have a good day.

Comment: These instructions are slightly misleading: you should look for the DLL inside the folder C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms** \11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91 for the WinForms version fo the control. If you are using WebForms, look in the WebForms folder. (the folder indicated will give a DLL that won't load and will throw an error)

Comment: Also, note that by manually selecting the DLLs in the **11** .x.x.x folder, you are selecting the components for Report Viewer 2012. Some versions of Visual Studio will show Report Viewer as an option ready to select without having to browse, but they're usually an older version. (typically version 10). Make sure you know which version you want (usually 11 is the one to go for and is the one that corresponds to Report Viewer 2012)